# Undefined reference to symbol 'gzclose'

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, qt-creator

I guess this is a linker error, but I've spent a lot of time and haven't find a working answer. I have an OpenCV C++ program, when I try to compile something of the style `cv::Mat newMatObject;` it gives me the error `/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.a(persistence.cpp.o): undefined reference to symbol 'gzclose'`.

The .pro file contains the following lines:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = QtTest
TEMPLATE = app

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/opencv
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lz -ltbb -ltiff

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        qttest.cpp

HEADERS  += qttest.h

FORMS    += qttest.ui
```

Am I **forgetting something/doing something wrong**?

### Some Info:

- Kubuntu 16.04 LTS 64 Bits
- Qt Creator 4.0.2, based on Qt 5.7.0
- OpenCV 2.4.13

### Addendum:

I had the program working properly with OpenCV 2.4.9, no other changes. I decided to move on to 2.4.13 because of the extended gui, which didn't work on 2.4.9. I downloaded OpenCV 2.4.13 from the [official website](http://opencv.org/downloads.html), and installed it with [this script](https://gist.github.com/arthurbeggs/06df46af94af7f261513934e56103b30/) (except for the wget and unzip, which were made manually), initially didn't `autoremove` the previous library, but I did after the issue came up and rerun the previous script again, to ensure proper installation.

### Edit 1:

Running

```
g++ -o opencvtest opencvtest.cpp `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs`
```

with similar lines of code provides the desired result without a problem.

Comment: May the downvoter please provide an explanation or a piece of advice to improve this question?

Answer (score 0):

Add `-lz` to your `LIBS`:

```
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lz
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I did previously, and I obtain 1181 undefined references (*exempli gratia* `undefined reference to 'tbb::task_scheduler_init::terminate()'`, `undefined reference to 'tbb::internal::allocate_continuation_proxy::allocate(unsigned long) const'`, *inter alia*). Also, have a look at the first edit I made in the question, where I state compiling a similar program from console does not produce an error.

Comment: These look like Intel tbb library, add it to linker dependencies too.

Comment: I did (added `-ltbb`), it still provides tons of undefined references (1156), it is weird, the program is only opening an image file. Kindly refer to [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqkmq.png), where some of the errors are shown (there are also undefined QString, QMetaObject, QObject, QWidget, *et cetera*).

Comment: For TIFF* you probably need `LIBS += -ltiff`, for undefined `QString`, `QObject` add `QT += core` to your .pro file, for `QWidget` either `QT += gui` for Qt4 or `QT += widgets` for Qt5.

Comment: I already have `QT += core gui`, also, remember that before adding `-lz`, these errors wouldn't appear, is that normal?, I posted in my question the full .pro file.

Comment: With that last edit I am getting now `/usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.a(grfmt_jpeg.cpp.o): undefined reference to symbol 'jpeg_resync_to_restart@@LIBJPEG_8.0'`